# Find (local) minima of function over interval

Tags: netlogo

I am building a decision making function for turtles how to apportion funds to reach a certain ratio of two parameters. To do so turtles find the most successful ratio among the other turtles and try to allocate their funds in a ratio that leads to the smallest difference between their ratio and the best ratio.

Mathematically that seems relatively easy to achieve by minimizing the function that calculates the difference between own and best ratio. Since it is a ratio the interval naturally is [0,1].

I wonder though how to implement this? I could compute a list of values and find the minimum with `min` but that seems a little clumsy. Unfortunately the Netlogo docs weren't of much help given my search terms. I think it's a rather standard problem, so am I missing a standard solution?

- bestRatio_t-1: a/b
- ownRatio_t-1: c/d
- Growth of a,b,c,d per tick: g
- fraction of growth: f

Minimizing `g(f) = a/b - (a + (g * f)) / (b + (g * (1-f)))` defined for the interval [0,1] should then yield the optimal fraction f, I think?

Comment: I think the way to go is the min function here. Something like let target-turtles other turtle with-min (abs my-ratio - best-ratio). Careful though, have something like if target-turtle != nobody just so the best ratio turtle doesn't try target itself (unless you want that)

Comment: You'll have to provide the math (function and constraints, along with the algorithm for best ratio).  As described above, it sounds like a turtle should just imitate the best performing turtle.

Comment: Alright, sorry for being imprecise. I added the math.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can actually just solve for the minimum analytically. Take the derivative of your function, solve for 0 algebraically. That tells you the `f` where there's either a maxima or minima (but not which it is) based on your parameters. Then you just evaluate your `f` at that point, at `f=0`, and at `f=1`, and see which is the smallest.

Otherwise, since I believe there's only one minima in this function, you can use either [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) or [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) to find that minima.

Another very simple and actually quite realistic strategy for many situations is just to randomly sample. Just evaluate the function at a bunch of random points and take the smallest.